# Regular Expression in PHP that looks like ABC-1234

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regex that validates the first column of the .csv file, the column must allow 3 - 5 alphabetic character, a Hyphen and a numeric value E,g. ABCD-123, EFG-4 or HIJKL-5678 This is in PHP.

below is the source code where I will need to apply that regex.

```
<?php
 $allowedColums = 3;
 //Open the file.
 $fileHandle = fopen("names.csv", "r");
 //Loop through the CSV rows.
 while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     //Dump out the row for the sake of clarity.
     $numcols = count($row);
     if ($numcols != $allowedColums){
         break;
     }
     echo " $row[0] ";
     $fisrtColumn = $row[0];
     $secondColumn = $row[1];
     $thirdColumn = $row[2];
     var_dump($row); 
 }

 fclose($fileHandle);
?>
```

Comment: Okay, and what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
^[A-Z]{3,5}-\d+$
```

Explanation:

1. `^` match beginning of string
2. `[A-Z]` match any capital letter. It wasn't specified but all your examples were capitalized. If case doesn't matter, you can do `[a-zA-Z]`.
3. `{3,5}` match the previous token (`[A-Z]`) a minimum of 3 times and a maximum of 5 times.
4. `-` match the `-` character.
5. `\d+` match one or more digits
6. `$` match end of string

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel Smith the above works, and thanks again for breaking it down. it really helps

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
[A-Z]{3,5}-\d+
```

If the string has to start with this use

```
^[A-Z]{3,5}-\d+
```